# Query MySql select exception

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm doing a app and I made a query where I get the pontuation of users inside a "room" where the users that have a certain tool activated doesn't show in the result. But I want to have my user in the result even if I have the tool activated.

```
SELECT users.id, users.username, users.profile_pic, room_players.points 
FROM tools_by_user_by_room, users, room_players 
WHERE room_players.room = 0 AND room_players.user = users.id AND tools_by_user_by_room.user = users.id AND tools_by_user_by_room.room = room_players.room AND tools_by_user_by_room.tool = 2 AND tools_by_user_by_room.active != 1
ORDER BY points DESC;
```

Well, imagine that the room has the `id = 0`, my user id is 1 and the the tool has `id = 2`.
What I have to do to appear in the result even if I have the tool (`id = 2`) activated (`active = 1`)?

Edit: Adding structured query (using ANSI-92) as requested in comments under my answer:

```
SELECT 
    users.id, 
    users.username, 
    users.profile_pic, 
    room_players.points 
FROM 
    room_players
        join users
            on room_players.user = users.id 
        join tools_by_user_by_room
            on tools_by_user_by_room.user = users.id 
            and tools_by_user_by_room.room = room_players.room
WHERE 
    room_players.room = 0 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.tool = 2 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.active != 1
ORDER BY 
    points DESC;
```

The answer to my question is:

```
`SELECT 
    users.id, 
    users.username, 
    users.profile_pic, 
    room_players.points 
FROM 
    room_players
        join users
            on room_players.user = users.id 
        join tools_by_user_by_room
            on tools_by_user_by_room.user = users.id 
            and tools_by_user_by_room.room = room_players.room
WHERE 
    (room_players.room = 0 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.tool = 2 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.active != 1) 
    OR (room_players.room = 0 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.tool = 2 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.active = 1
    AND users.id = 1)
ORDER BY 
    points DESC;`
```

Comment: This query is working. This gives me the users and pontuations that don't have the the tool activated it means `ools_by_user_by_room.active != 1`. But I want the users and pontuations that don't have the tool activated, and my pontuation even if I have the tool activated. It mean that I want to add an exception to my user id.

Comment: The right answer is in the post. I edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

I have reformatted the code to make it (at least for me) easier to understand your code. This is your original query:

```
SELECT 
    users.id, 
    users.username, 
    users.profile_pic, 
    room_players.points 
FROM 
    room_players
        join users
            on room_players.user = users.id 
        join tools_by_user_by_room
            on tools_by_user_by_room.user = users.id 
            and tools_by_user_by_room.room = room_players.room
WHERE 
    room_players.room = 0 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.tool = 2 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.active != 1
ORDER BY 
    points DESC;
```

Would you not be able to now get your desired results simply by changing the where condition?

```
SELECT 
    users.id, 
    users.username, 
    users.profile_pic, 
    room_players.points 
FROM 
    room_players
        join users
            on room_players.user = users.id 
        join tools_by_user_by_room
            on tools_by_user_by_room.user = users.id 
            and tools_by_user_by_room.room = room_players.room
WHERE 
    room_players.room = 0 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.tool = 2 
    AND tools_by_user_by_room.active = 1
    and user.id=1
ORDER BY 
    points DESC;
```

Comment: Nice to see the query structured. Consider adding the original one (with your fixed indenting) to the OP's question.

Comment: The second query gives me only my pontuation if I have the tool activated. I want all users pontuation that don't have the tool activated (`tools_by_user_by_room.active != 1`) and my pontuation even if have the tool activated.

Comment: Your question stated `What I have to do to appear in the result even if I have the tool (id = 2) activated (active = 1)?` meaning you wanted it activated?

Comment: If you want deactivated then just flip the `=` in the second query to a `!=`?

Comment: I know that. But I want an exception, it means that I want the pontuation and users that dont have the tool activated (`!=`) but I want to include an exceptional user to the result with the `users.id = 1` (even if he have the tool activated). Did you understand?